# If a function uses 'new' and returns the variable, and if we don't assign it in our main, can we delete it?

Tags: c++, dynamic

I know that whenever we allocate something into the heap, we must delete it. So I have a question, which I'll explain with help of an example.

Let's say `size` is a function that uses the `new` operator.

```
int size (...){
       ...
       int *p = new int[1];
       *p = 5;
       ...
       return *p;
}
```

I have allocated some memory in the `heap` so I must delete it, but if in my `main` function I do this...

```
int main(){
     int i = 0;
     if (i < size(...)){     // <- here
         ...
     }
}
```

As you can see I am not assigning `size(...)` to anything. My question is can we deallocate memory in such a situation, if yes then how?

Comment: No, you can't delete that memory, sinc you have no longer access to the pointer needed for the corresponding `delete`call.

Comment: When `size()` returns, the pointer `p` (which holds the pointer resulting from the `new` expression) ceases to exist.     So that dynamically allocated memory cannot be released, and will be leaked.    And assigning the return value from `size()` to something would not change that, since the return value of `size()` is a COPY (i.e. a distinct variable) of the value that your code stored in `*p`.

Comment: Dude  @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ I don't understand classes yet, please don't close my question, can you open it again.

Comment: @Peter what should be the best practice? If we want to use new in our function.

Comment: @blackmamba Nothing to do with classes. It's all well explained in the duplicate. I'll not reopen your question unless you [edit] it to explain in more depth why the answers in the duplicate don't apply well for your problem.